# Menu not appearing in custom theme

Tags: customization, menus, add-theme-support

I made a custom theme, but the menu is not showing in appearance section. I created a separate function file named `function.php` and the code is:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'new-menu', __( 'New Menu' ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

and calling in `header.php`, the code is:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'new-menu' ) );
```

How to manage it?

When I create new pages, it shows as menu.

Answer (score 1):

I make a mistake while making a function file.
Its correct name is ***functions.php*** not **function.php**..